# How to set the keyboard layout for OpenIndiana Hipster?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, openindiana

Sadly OpenIndiana Hipster no longer ask for keyboard-layout during installation, so I'm stuck with American layout on a Norwegian keyboard.  I was therefor wondering what the correct way (some file, some svc-service, ...) of changing the default keyboard-layout is?

I would prefer if one change worked for both the VirtualTerminals and the GUI (X) - but if it must be changed separately, that is alright too.